# How we can have 2 surfaces in thin film when we calculate intensity surface tension?

Tags: surface-tension

I have already seen that this question was asked earlier, but the answer is not specific. How is it physically possible that when the wire in this experiment can divide this liquid from soap into two parts. what happens to the contact between the soap and the wire and thus explains this formula F / 2L or is it something else. I am interested in the physical explanation of this phenomenon. How it is possible to form two surfaces. It only seems logical to me and that is that wire when it comes in contact with the liquid "divides the liquid into two parts. I would ask you for an explanation.Here is some pictures from earlier similar questions
[image]
[image]

Comment: The top image shows a liquid thin film in the shape of a rectangle (shaded area) **in air**. The planar film is connected at all four sides. The wire does not divide "soap from liquid". Does this answer your question?